# Jquery on click hide the next added element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a button, which on every click gives the dropdown element.
Now i need to add the check box above the dropdown - which i have done, but this checkbox element should appear only for the first time.

[image]

**The problem** is , on every click, i get both dropdown associated with checkbox like below.

[image]

I need checkbox only for the 1st time button click- along with dropdown.
SO for the 2nd time button click, i tried to hide the checkbox, but the previous checkbox is getting hidden.

```
public function getPreferenceKeysAction() {
....
<div style="margin:2px 0px 15px 0px;">
    <input id = "mydd" type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="RegisteredUsers"> Registered Users</input><br>
    <input id = "mydd" type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="RegisteredUsers"> Opted Users</input><br>
}
```

**in JS**

```
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        if($("#mydd").length){
            alert("The element you're testing is present.");
            $("#mydd").hide();
        }
        else{
            alert("NOt present.");

        }
});
```

Comment: Do you use this presented JS code to find the problem or is a part of your codes?

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a class to the element or a data attribute.

With jQuery both are easy to achive.
If you want to use a class just change data method to hasClass and addClass

just do a

```
$btn = $(this);
// Check if the element has data attribute used
if ( $btn.data('used') != 'true' ) {
    // Add data attribute used to element 
    $btn.data('used', 'true')
    // Do whats needed for the first time it's clicked.
} else {
    // The element has been used already
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you id="mydd" to class="mydd", you should use id with a unique value, doing that you can hide the elements skipping 2 of them, like this.

```
$('.mydd').slice(2).hide();
```

If you want to hide the div wrapping your checkbox, add .parent()

```
$('.mydd').parent().slice(1).hide();
```